# Element loading issues in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm pretty muddled down by Protractor at the moment.

It seems that sometimes my elements load in time for the next action to occur on them, and sometimes they do not. I'm guessing it has to do with it's async nature.

SO anyway, for example, sometimes this code passes, and sometimes it doesn't:

```
it('should create an audience using an existing audience and should be able to filter and search for that audience', function () {
        page.audienceTab.click();
        $('.panel-list .row .panel-list-header .btn').click();
        $('.panel-list div .btn').click();
        $('.edit-audience .row .col-md-3 accordion .panel-group .name-filter .panel-collapse .panel-body section input').sendKeys('test-audience');
        $('.expose-offset button').click();
        $('.col-xs-4 input').sendKeys('test-audience');
        expect($('.panel-list .panel h3').getText()).toEqual('test-audience');
    });
```

Anyway this could be fixed so that elements would be guaranteed to load before the next action was triggered?

Comment: Where does it fail and how? Thanks.

Comment: It's erring out about 50% of the time at $('.panel-list .row .panel-list-header .btn').click(); I've verified that the element does indeed exist.

Comment: So the error comes out as: Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".panel-list .row .panel-list-header .btn")

Answer (score 1):

You can try *resolving the `click` promise explicitly*:

```
page.audienceTab.click().then(function () {
    $('.panel-list .row .panel-list-header .btn').click();
    $('.panel-list div .btn').click();
    $('.edit-audience .row .col-md-3 accordion .panel-group .name-filter .panel-collapse .panel-body section input').sendKeys('test-audience');
    $('.expose-offset button').click();
    $('.col-xs-4 input').sendKeys('test-audience');
    expect($('.panel-list .panel h3').getText()).toEqual('test-audience');
});
```

Or, *waiting for an element to be present* before making a click:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    button = $('.panel-list .row .panel-list-header .btn');
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(button), 5000);
button.click();
// rest of the test
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it helps when you wrap the final expect in a .then() function, like:

```
$('.col-xs-4 input').sendKeys('test-audience').then(function() {
  expect($('.panel-list .panel h3').getText()).toEqual('test-audience');
});
```